# Magento 2 Change date format DD/MM/YY in all date fields ( my orders and other pages )

Tags: magento2, dateformat

My magento2 site date format is no like a MM/DD/YY format but I want to change DD/MM/YY format in my orders page and all other date fields. Please help me I tried and changed configuration settings JavaScript calendar but no changes in dates. Please help me by changing programmatically.

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/set-date-format-in-magento-2-by-your-own/

Comment: Rk Rathod I tried but not working

Comment: my order page on frontend side ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the date format by using the following code.

```
protected $timezone;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
......
)
{
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
}

$dateTimeZone = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($yourdate))->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Where do I add this code?